# drag textbox with mouse on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

i want to ask how to move text on a image. actually i m designing online design shirt website for that m giving user the facility to add text on image. how user adjust text position on image. here is my code it is working and text is written on image but we cannot move it on image using mouse cursor. kindly help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace roughly
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = Request.Form["TextBox1"];



            Bitmap bitMapImage = new
   System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("dallen.jpg"));
            Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
            graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphicImage.DrawString (value,
   new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold),
   SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(250, 300));



            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
           bitMapImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            graphicImage.Dispose();
            bitMapImage.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be reinventing the wheel, why not try this-

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/